# How to avoid collapsing with shinyWidgets dropdown and a datatable

Tags: r, shiny, shinywidgets

I want to display a spreadsheet with some information in `shinyWidgets` **dropdown**, sometimes spanning multiple pages.

If you click on the next page, the dropdown closes again.
**How can I avoid this?**

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)

ui <- fluidPage(
  br(),br(),br(),
  p("How to go to the next page, without collapsing?"),
  uiOutput("irisdrop", inline = TRUE)
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$irisdrop <- renderUI({
    dropdown(circle = FALSE, inputId = "iris",
             label = "iris", status = "primary", 
             datatable(iris, rownames = NULL,
                       height = "100%",
                       selection = "none"
             )
    )
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Probably not what you are looking for, but it doesn't happen with `dropdownButton` from `shinydashboard`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do something like this -

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(DT)


ui <- fluidPage(
  dropdownButton(
    inputId = "iris",
    label = "iris",
    icon = icon("sliders"),
    status = "primary",
    circle = FALSE,
    DT::dataTableOutput("iris_tb")
  )
)


server <- function(input, output, session) {

  output$iris_tb <- DT::renderDataTable({

    datatable(iris, rownames = NULL,
              height = "100%",
              selection = "none"
    )

  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

**Note:** You can even use `dropdown()` instead of `dropdownButton()`  from `shinyWidgets` package.

`dropdown()` is similar to `dropdownButton()` but it don't use Bootstrap, so you can put `pickerInput` in it. Moreover you can add animations on the appearance / disappearance of the dropdown with `animate.css`.

For more detail, you can look at the page 30 of the following document -

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/shinyWidgets/shinyWidgets.pdf

Comment: Thank you, this also works if the `dropdown` is created in the server function.